# How to get from theory to a working Industry Control System?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

EE Student here who recently finished the classical control theory class. I was wondering the process of how the industry or anyone goes from drawing block diagrams to actually implementing in hardware.
For example, I'm trying to design a system that keeps a battery from reaching a threshold temperature without having the battery reduce its power output. I'm having trouble visualizing how I will go from a PID controller in theory to the actual hardware system.

Comment: How do you normally cool things?

Comment: Start by showing your block diagram.

Comment: Questions here must be specifically answerable; this is not.  Your topic belongs in a discussion forum rather than here.

Comment: That logic is so flawed, 99% of the time there are many ways to solve a problem. Its up to the reader to filter all the inputs and take what they want from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to have the same feeling when I were introduced to control systems. We always worked on this perfect little DC motor with a nicely made test bench with good sensors etc.

Implementing the hardware is usually, drivers (high/low side), communication protocols, sensors networks, this isn't really the worst thing.

Always research your options https://www.electronicdesign.com/electromechanical/add-simple-temperature-monitoring-battery-management-systems

**So my way to go about this -**

1. Identify your sensors and actuators. (Learn all you can about them most important step!!)
2. Identify your system. (disturbances, integrating influences, unlinearities etc.)
3. Choose a proper control scheme. (Fuzzy logic, cascaded, MIMO etc.)
4. Draw a block diagram. (then think about the system as a whole and redraw it 10 times)
5. Implement and tune accordingly.

That's the quick and dirty, as you gain experience you will start to look at more advanced things, such as the influence of clock jitter, automatic gain scheduleing etc.

Comment: First thing is to list **all** the functionalities you want, deciding to add one at the end of the process is fatal...

Comment: There is some good stuff here, so it is unfair to mark this as wrong or not useful, but the design process normally starts with *requirements*.

Comment: This is why we do not allow broad question on stack exchange, but only questions which can be specifically answered.  This question cannot be.